# Insert multiple lines of hyperlinks in HTML by Python

Tags: python, html

To display multiple lines in html body, simple codes:

```
websites = ["https://www.reddit.com/","https://en.wikipedia.org/","https://www.facebook.com/"]

html = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Hi, friend</h1>
<p>$websites!</p>

</body>
</html>
"""

html = Template(html).safe_substitute(websites = "<p>".join(websites))
```

Now I want to change the links to hyperlinks with friendly names.

```
names = ["News", "Info", "Media"]
```

Changed the line to:

```
<p><a href=$websites>$names</a></p>
```

and:

```
html = Template(html).safe_substitute(websites = "<p>".join(websites),
                                        names= "<p>".join(names))
```

What I want in the html to show is:

[News](https://www.reddit.com/)

[Info](https://en.wikipedia.org/)

[Media](https://www.facebook.com/)

But it doesn't show properly. What's the right way to do that?

Comment: What does the actual HTML you get look like? Do you know what it should like? How exactly does it differ, at the HTML level?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, thanks for the comment. Above is the actual, I created it for email content. and 1 line for header, as I edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do `'<p>'.join(websites)`. This will create a string by joining all the elements of a list and stick the `'<p>'` between them.

so that gives you `"https://www.reddit.com/<p>https://en.wikipedia.org/"<p>https://www.facebook.com/"` which is not what you want (I don't think It's valid as well).

You don't have any `<a>` link tags. So you need to Create those.
The `href` will point to the website and inside the `<a>` tag you have the name you want to appear

```html
<a href={link}>{link_name}</a>
```

This is what you want to do:

```py
websites = ["https://www.reddit.com/","https://en.wikipedia.org/","https://www.facebook.com/"]

html = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>$websites</p>

</body>
</html>
"""

tag_names = ['News', 'Info', 'Media']
a_links = '<br/>'.join([f'<a href={link}>{link_name}</a>' for link, link_name in zip(websites, tag_names)])

html = Template(html).safe_substitute(websites=a_links)
```